# LightGBM Fatal Length, (y) label is not same with data shape shows match ok

Tags: python-3.x, xgboost, lightgbm

**Problem**

Developing a LightGBM machine learning model with shapes that are matching, fixed data to match shapes. Problem is a Fatal length of label that is not same with data. Looking for advise on how to resolve fatal length of label for LightGBM.

**Shape of Data**

```
print(y_train.shape)
print(X_train.shape)
print(X_test.shape)

y_train: (1019169,)
X_train: (1019169, 12)
X_test: (1019169, 12)
```

However, with shape[-1] is used, the following shapes

```
print(y_train.shape[-1])
print(X_train.shape[-1])
print(X_test.shape[-1])

y_train: 1019169
X_train: 12
X_test: 12
```

Data is found on Kaggle new york city taxi datasets.

Code:

```
lgb_params = {
    'metric': 'rmse',
    'num_leaves': 31, 
    'objective': 'binary',
    'is_training_metric': True}

X_train = X_train[['passenger_count', 'pickup_longitude', 'pickup_latitude', 'dropoff_latitude', 'trip_duration', 'store_fwd_flag', 'direction', 'month', 'week', 'weekday', 'hour', 'minute_oftheday']]
X_test = X_train[['passenger_count', 'pickup_longitude', 'pickup_latitude', 'dropoff_latitude', 'trip_duration', 'store_fwd_flag', 'direction', 'month', 'week', 'weekday', 'hour', 'minute_oftheday']]


#lgb.Dataset.subset(used_columns: List[str]) -> lgb.Dataset
lgb_train = lgb.Dataset(X_train, y_train)
lgb_test = lgb.Dataset(X_test, y_test)
lgb_model = lgb.train(lgb_params, lgb_train, num_boost_round=10, 
                      valid_sets=[lgb_train, lgb_test], 
                      early_stopping_rounds=6)
```

The error trace is here:

```
[LightGBM] [Warning] Contains only one class
[LightGBM] [Info] Number of positive: 1019169, number of negative: 0
[LightGBM] [Warning] Auto-choosing row-wise multi-threading, the overhead of testing was 0.060011 seconds.
You can set `force_row_wise=true` to remove the overhead.
And if memory is not enough, you can set `force_col_wise=true`.
[LightGBM] [Info] Total Bins 1606
[LightGBM] [Info] Number of data points in the train set: 1019169, number of used features: 12
[LightGBM] [Fatal] Length of label is not same with #data
```

Expected outcome: a LightGBM trained model and MSE performance evaluation

Answer (score 0):

Solved problem, y_train was incorrect. Updated y_train to after train/test split for correct shape.